# How to display list items in gridview?

Tags: c#

//This list contains a lot of values

```
        List<Säljare> säljare = new List<Säljare>();
```

//sort list

```
        int[] nivåOrder = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        säljare = säljare.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(nivåOrder, x.Nivå)).ToList();
```

//output list into gridview

```
        dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Add(säljare);
        dgvViewsäljare.Rows[dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Count - 1].Tag = nySäljare;
```

/*The output I get is "Systems.Collections.Generic.List[WindowsFormsApp62.form1+Säljare]
Why? and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance
*/

Comment: You're adding the entire list as a single row. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) (I think this is the right documentation), you can either add rows one at a time, or you can add rows all at once by passing an array (not a list). This means you can either loop through each item and call `Add(item)` or you can convert your array to a list and pass it.

Answer (score -1):

```
dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;
```

Comment: This will also replace everything in the view, which is not what the OP is asking. How do you know they don't already have other things in there they would like to keep?